# How to type [TAB] in Total Commander "Compare" editor?

Tags: total-commander, file-comparison

I love to use Total Commander "Compare by content" editor. However, when I press [TAB], it doesn't type it in the source, it just rotates the focus over different GUI buttons.

How do I type [TAB] in the Total Commander "Compare" editor?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key) press
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>9</kbd> in the Editor Window

Comment: oh, yeah, good old last resort :-D Note that it must be done on the numerical keyboard; so on my Dell laptop it's `Alt` + `Fn` + `M` `9` :-)

Comment: accepting this as the only solution for now, although I would prefer simpler solution though :-)